# Recursive approach to find shortest path

Tags: java, algorithm

```
    ########
    #C....G#
    ##.##C##
    #..C..S#
    #C.....#
    ########

S- starting Point
G-Goal
"#"- Blocked Path
"."- Free Paths
"C"- Checkpoints must be visited
```

**Any Points can be visited(S,G,C,".") can be visited more than once. `Finally` should end at G**.

I want to find the shortest path between S and G. I am using BFS approach to find it but the problem with it it generates **thousands of threads**. My code works fine for 4x4 array but with a big array 50x50 it crashes:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Please help me to improve my approach to solve this problem.

```
public void distancecalculator(char[][] problem ,Point start ,int distancefound, ArrayList<Point> refernce) {

    Point p = new Point();
    LinkedList<Point> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(start);
    int []x = {1,-1,0,0};
    int []y = {0,0,1,-1};
    int[][]dist = new int[m][n];
    for(int []a : dist){
        Arrays.fill(a,-1);
    }
    if(distanceend==true)
        enddistance = dist;
    dist[start.x][start.y] = distancefound;

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
    //  if(distanceend == true)
        p = q.removeFirst();
    //  else
    //      p = q.getFirst();
    //      ExecutorService execute = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int a = p.x + x[i];
            int b = p.y + y[i];

            if (a >= 0 && b >= 0 && a < m && b < n && dist[a][b] == -1 && problem[a][b] != '#' ) {

                dist[a][b] = 1 + dist[p.x][p.y];
                if (distanceend==true)
                {
                    enddistance[a][b] = dist[a][b];
                    q.add(new Point(a,b));
                }
                if (distanceend==false)
                {
                    //  virtual++;
                    Point  neworigin =  new Point();
                    neworigin.x = a;
                    neworigin.y = b;
                    refernce.add(neworigin);
                    char[][] newproblem =  new char[m][n];
                    //newproblem = problem;
                    int k=0;
                    for(int s=0 ;s<m;s++)
                    {
                        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                        {
                            newproblem[s][j] = problem[s][j];
                            if(problem[a][b]=='@')
                                newproblem[a][b]= '.';
                            if(newproblem[s][j]=='@')
                                k=k+1;
                        }

                    }
                    //  System.out.println(k)
                    // System.out.println("1");

                    System.out.println(neworigin);
                    if(k>0)
                    {
                        ArrayList<Point> sompathak =  (ArrayList<Point>)refernce.clone();

                        solver s = new solver(newproblem , neworigin,dist[a][b] , refernce );

                        som =  new Thread(s);
                        som.start();

                        // execute.submit(s);
                    }

                    if(k==0)
                    {    // System.out.println("why god");

                        if(enddistance[a][b]!=-1)
                        {  

                            dist[a][b] = dist[a][b] + enddistance[a][b];

                            temp2 = dist[a][b];
                            System.out.println("Answer is "+ temp2);

                            System.exit(1);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

distanceend boolean expression is used if I am calculation the distance from end to each point (-1 if not possible) or I am solving the problem (finding the shortest distance)

Answer (score 1):

As *Kyllopardium* already said, BFS eats a lot of memory, but your problem is that you try to start a new Thread which is not going in your case. This can be caused by the RAM, by the Thread Limit of your OS, and so on.

An easier solution would be to use Thread Pools. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) article from Oracle about it. A Thread Pool as you need it has some Threads called "Worker Threads" that handle your actions. If there is currently no worker thread available, and no one could be started (for what reasons ever), your job is placed in a queue until it can be executed by a worker thread that currently has no job. This will make sure that Exceptions like this won't be thrown.

Comment: I was just heading out to find that link :)